# Searching SortedSet<String>

Tags: java, string, collections, set

i'm working on a word game, one of its methods is a scramble method, it should take String s then shuffle it using Collections.shuffle(ListOfSChars); and check if scramble is within SortedSet Dictionary. if dictionary.contains(scramble) && scramble != s output scramble

the example in my code is grapes, it should output any possible word of grapes if 2 conditions are true,
-First, new scrambled word can't be grapes. wordsSet.contains(scramble)
-Second, new scrambled word has to be within dictionary. scramble != s

my code outputs grapes ignoring (if (wordsSet.contains(scramble) && scramble != s))

how do i avoid returning the same string ?

Thanks,

```
    public class F
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String s = "grapes";
        SortedSet<String> dictionary = new TreeSet<String>(EnglishWords);
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char c : s.toCharArray)
            list.add(c);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        String scramble = "";
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : list)
            sb1.append(c);
        scramble = sb1.toString();
        sb1.setLength(0);
        boolean found = false;
        while (found != true)
        {
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            for (char c : list)
                sb1.append(c);
            scramble = sb1.toString();
            sb1.setLength(0);
            if (wordsSet.contains(scramble) && scramble != s)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            } else if (!wordsSet.contains(scramble))
            {
                found = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("scrambled word is " + scramble);
    }

}
```

Comment: Never compare (general) objects using == (!=) - it will only return true for the same object.

Comment: Won't this infinite loop if there are no matches?

Comment: You should use permutations on the input string rather than random shuffle. With shuffle you will be running the same check multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
!scramble.equals(s)
```

instead of

```
scramble != s
```

The former is how you properly compare strings in Java.